# How to make UIImage move every hour?

Tags: uiimage, mkmapview, swift3, xcode8

Hey so I'm working on a simple app and I want this image on a map to move closer hour by hour towards the user location. I can't figure out where to start, can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift has a Timer class.  There are several overloads for Timer.init.  The newer block based one works like this:

```
    let hour = TimeInterval(60 * 60) //60 seconds per min * 60 min per hour = 360 seconds per hour
    let timer = Timer.init(timeInterval: hour, repeats: true) { timer in
        //Do hourly update stuff here
    }
```

Comment: Okay, thanks tahat helps me with the time part, but what code would I use to make the image move towards the user location

Comment: Its not clear what you want to do.  Do you want an animation? UIView.animate.  Do you just want to move the image? Linearly interpolate its inital center and destination center by the elapsed value as a proportion of total time and update its .center property.

Comment: I literally just want to move the image. Not animated